# Vector parametrization of the line that passes through two vectors.

Tags: calculus, vectors, parametrization

How would I find the vector parametrization  $()$  of the line  $L$  that passes through the points  $(2,1,4)$  and  $(5,6,7)$?

So I found a directional vector: $(3,5,3)$.

What do I do next?

Comment: Find a direction vector for the line; make $\mathbf r(0)=(2,1,4)$ and $\mathbf r(1)=5,6,7)$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner thanks, now what do i do with that

Comment: It will be $r=(2,1,4)+t(3,5,3)=(3t+2,5t+1,3t+4)$.

Comment: @SarGe thanks brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a direction vector $(3,5,3)=(5,6,7)-(2,1,4)$,

so the line can be parametrized as $(2,1,4)+t(3,5,3)=(2+3t,1+5t,4+3t)$.

Note that $\mathbf r(0)=(2,1,4)$ and $\mathbf r(1)=(5,6,7)$.

Comment: thanks, i got it now. thank u for all the help it makes sense now